# Get Date ISO String without timezone subtraction

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to get a Date string without the timezone addition/subtraction.
Today, setting a timezone with GMT +13 in my OS, creating a new Date() object and then getting the toISOString() of this Date, one day will be subtracted.

So, today is 11/02, if I set the OS time to GMT +13 and do this:

```
let dateExample = new Date()
dateExample.toISOString() // this returns 2021-02-10T22:50:33.171Z
```

and I need a yyyy-mm-dd string in correct day (2021-02-11). How can I have it?

Thank you.

Comment: this is unclear, you want to get your local date time with just   yyyy-mm-dd  values ? or the unversal date time at GMT zero ?

Comment: One day isn't being subtracted, *toISOString* returns UTC values so you're seeing the UTC date, not your local date. QnD: `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')` but beware *toLocale\** methods are not necessarily consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this string yourself:

```js
const d = new Date();

const s = d.getFullYear().toString().padStart(4, '0')
          + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
          + '-' + d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

console.log(s);
```

Don't forget to add 1 to the month, as `getMonth` returns months 0-11, not 1-12.

Comment: 'cos [formatting dates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date) hasn't been covered before… ;-)

Comment: Indeed. But like oh so many other topics on Stack Overflow, sometimes hunting down an exact duplicate question with a good accepted answer takes longer than writing the answer again.  ;-)  (Feel free to close as dup.)

Comment: I fully agree, nice to see a concise, quality answer. Sometimes when marking a duplicate I'll also link directly to a good answer, but the time and effort can be considerable.